# Evaluations of Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials at $q=-1$ and $q=1$

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, kazhdan-lusztig

I am looking for some references about the meaning (if any) of the evaluations of Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials of Coxeter groups at the integers $1$ and $-1$. Even if this is meaningful only by imposing additional assumptions on the Coxeter group or on the interval, it would fine.

In particular, does the sign of $P_{x,y}(-1)$ reflect any particular property of interest in mathematics?

Unfortunately, although this question seems pretty natural and I expect someone to have thought about it, neither zbMath nor MathSciNet are helping with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Certainly the evaluations at one are significant: they enter into the original KL conjectures relating the characters of Verma modules to the simples and vice-versa. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan%E2%80%93Lusztig_polynomial